# ScrollTop in a div? Can I pause, stop, speed up and slow down the scroll?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with song lyrics in it that scrolls on a button click. This is working fine. I am now trying to get other functions working with very little luck.

I would like to have buttons to pause the scroll in the current position and start from that position if I click the pause button again, 
Stop the scroll and reset to the start of the lyrics,
Speed up the scrolling and slow down the scrolling.

I haven't really worked on the speed up and slow down bits yet, But I have tried quite a few things with the pause and stop. So far no luck.

This is the scroll code I am using:

```
$('#lyricsauto').click(function() {
  var div = $('#lyricwrap');
  setInterval(function() {
    var pos = div.scrollTop();
    div.scrollTop(pos + 1);
  }, 800);
});
```

I also have set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tlm2408/kdnzze9k/50/) to play around with that includes a few of the many things I have tried.

I have found many examples to stop scrolltop, but none of them seem to work in this scenario. I know this is a lot to ask, so I appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to store the reference to the interval and then use `clearInterval()` in the pause/stop actions to end it.

You can also use a single variable to control how much to scroll by which you can then increase or decrease in the handlers for the speed up/slow down buttons. Try this:

```js
var interval, scrollInc = 1, $div = $('#lyricwrap');

$('#lyricsauto').click(function() {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    var pos = $div.scrollTop();
    $div.scrollTop(pos + scrollInc);
  }, 800);
});

$("#pausescroll").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

$("#stopscroll").click(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  scrollInc = 1;
  $div.scrollTop(0);
});

$('#fasterscroll').click(function() {
  scrollInc++;
})

$('#slowerscroll').click(function() {
  scrollInc = Math.max(1, --scrollInc);
})
```

```css
#lyricwrap {
  position: fixed;
  height: 560px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#lyricstop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 120px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
}
#lyricstop button {
  width: 90px;
  float: left;
}

#pre {
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: pre-line;
  font: bold 12px Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="details">
  I have only been working on the pause and stop functions so far, I really want to get the others working too, but at least pause and stop. Pause should pause the scroll in the current position. Stop should Reset the lyrics at the start and not scroll
  anymore. Speed up should speed up the scroll by x amount... not sure how much yet. Slow down should slow the scroll down by x amount.
</div>

<div id="rightbox">
  <div id="lyricwrap">
    <div id="lyricstop">
      <button id="lyricsauto">Auto Scroll</button>
      <button id="pausescroll">pause scroll</button>
      <button id="stopscroll">stop scroll</button>
      <button id="fasterscroll">speed up</button>
      <button id="slowerscroll">slow down</button>
    </div>

    <div id="pre">Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this
      div
      <br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the curren Lyrics
      for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br>      could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing
      song
      <br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing
      song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br>      Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br> Lyrics for the current<br> playing song<br> are here<br> this div<br> could be any length<br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Also note that I tidied your CSS a little.

Comment: Wow so quick. Thank you so much Rory That works very well.

Comment: No problem, glad to help